# How to get dnorm curve using R

Tags: r, statistics, curve

```
x1000 <- rep(NA, 1000)
N = 10

for(i in 1:1000){
  x1000[i] <- mean(rpois(1000, 0.3))
}
hist(x1000, freq = F)

curve(dnorm(x1000, mean = 0.3, sd = sqrt(0.3)))
```

I'm trying to get the overlaid curve. However, it gives me:

```
Error in curve(dnorm(x1000, mean = 0.3, sd = sqrt(0.3))) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, this is what you asked for (technically):

```
hist(x1000, col="red", freq=F)
curve( dnorm(x, mean=.3,sd=sqrt(.3)), col="blue", add=T) # expression containing 'x'
```

[image]

But what I think you *really* want is:

```
curve( dnorm(x, mean=mean(x1000),sd=sd(x1000)), col="blue", add=T)
```

[image]

Or:

```
curve( dnorm(x, mean=mean(x1000),sd=sqrt(mean(x1000)/length(x1000)), col="blue", add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the user "really wants" `curve( dnorm(x, mean=.3,sd=sqrt(.3/1000), col="blue", add=T) ` (mean / Standard error of mean)

Comment: He did miscalculate the standard deviation as he is plotting the sampling distribution of the mean and therefore wants the standard error of the mean (sigma/sqrt(n)). sd(x1000) is an estimate of that (hence your graphy works). because x1000 is a sample of means (not raw data).

Comment: @mnel I see. Yes, you're probably right. I fixed the parentheses / location of parameters (they were just slightly off) in your version and added it. Cheers.